# What is the purpose of LDAP OIDs?

Tags: ldap

LDAP OIDs globally identify objects and are universally unique. Why is this needed?

Wouldn't it make more sense to just have unique identifiers within your own database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is globally unique to be able to share schemas ;)

If you take the objectClass `inetOrgPerson`, it is used by multiple implementation of the LDAP protocol with the same schema as LDAP is a protocol which can be implemented.

If you want for example to create an application which is based on a LDAP directory and use custom schemas, you will need to provide them, and you need to be sure that the OIDs you used are not conflicting with the schema already used by the directory in which one it will be used.

Answer (score -1):

> LDAP OIDs globally identify objects and are universally unique.

No they don't. They identify *syntaxes:* object schemas and attribute types.

> Why is this needed?

To identify syntaxes globally and uniquely.

> Wouldn't it make more sense to just have unique identifiers within your own database?

No.

Comment: Straight from Wikipedia: `object identifiers or OIDs are an identifier mechanism standardized by the International Telecommunications Union (ITU) and ISO/IEC for naming any object, concept, or "thing" with a globally unambiguous persistent name.`
The slides of my course literally say that `Objects have an object identifier` and `they are universally unique`. Even if the slides (and Wikipedia) are wrong, and they only identify syntaxes, you still haven't answered my question. What is the purpose of them being globally unique and registered with IANA?

Comment: 1. [Wikipedia is not a reliable resource](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedia_is_not_a_reliable_source). 2. If you had bothered to read Wikipedia further, you would have found 'Within X.500 and LDAP schemas and protocols, OIDs uniquely name each attribute type and object class, and other elements of schema.' That is to say, syntax. 3. I can't answer for the slides of your course. 4. The purpose of globally unique identifiers is to be globally unique.

Comment: Of course only you decide which of the contradicting definitions is correct... But let's agree that it only identifies syntax. What is the purpose of them being globally unique? Why would I want to register my syntax with IANA. What advantages do I get for my syntax being globally identifiable?

Comment: The purpose of OIDs is to allow interoperability between clients and servers  as well as discovery of the schema and capabilities. Any schema specific to your enterprise doesn't have to be  globally identifiable, but at least should have a unique identifier.